# Has my breaker gone bad?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I have a 20 amp breaker that recently tripped.  I tried unplugging a couple of appliances ( was running too much at that point) and resetting the breaker.  I tried turning the breaker off but it did not click and feel firm in the off position like it normally would.  Once I reset it, it tripped again almost instantly.  Also, the lights in the home dimmed slightly just before it tripped.

Is this a sign of a bad breaker or a wiring problem?

Comment: What all is on this circuit that tripped?

Comment: Also, what make and model is the breaker in question?

Comment: Unplug all appliances on this circuit and try again.

Comment: To answer your question: yes that is what circuit breakers are there for.

Comment: The breaker had several appliances such as an airfryer, dishwasher, and a Keurig coffee maker which was just turned on before the breaker tripped. Only the airfryer and coffee maker were running at the time of the trip. The breaker and box are Square D.   I have unplugged and retried several times with the same results.

Comment: I would be concerned that the insulation in some of the wiring was damaged by the overload. There are brands of breakers that have failures similar to your description. If you disconnect the appliances and resetting the breaker causes a trip with the lights flickering this circuit wiring needs to be checked out to find the location of the short. And evaluate if the existing wires need to be replaced or possibly just repaired in a box.  The brand and type of breaker could provide more on-site.

Comment: Are the air fryer and coffee maker in the same outlet?

Comment: No they are on separate outlets but are only a few feet from each other.

Comment: When I turn off other breakers in the box I get a firm feeling that it is securely in the off position along with a loud click.  With  this breaker I get no sound and do not get a feeling the that the switch is securely in the off position

Comment: It is entirely possible the breaker is bad. If you repeatedly blow breakers they do wear out.  A quite reasonable course of action to replace the breaker (same rating of course!).   I don't know why the dishwasher isn't on its own circuit, but the washer + fryer run together surely exceed 20 amps.

Answer (score 4):

Your description would indicate a severe short to ground. I would also think about changing out the breaker as this type of short may have damaged it. you need to start opening up boxes, pull out the wiring and look for a damaged wire. Once again from what you are describing it shouldn't be hard to find.

PS to all DIYlfers please do not keep trying to reset a breaker multiple times that has tripped. The only thing you can accomplish is further damage to your circuit and any appliance or device you may have attached to it. If you get a trip you should remove all portable equipment and appliances as you can. Then reset the breaker and see if it trips. If it does trip then **leave it off** until you can determine what is causing the trip. This advice not only has financial considerations but also has a high safety risk for starting a fire.

Stay safe in you endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this sounds to me like a dead short as well.  Additionally, it sounds like this short resulted from an overloading situation.  I would start pulling plugs and looking for burned wires.